# why oracle is saying invalid character?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am very new to Oracle, While i am practicing some examples i encountered with the problem "*invalid character (SQL-HY000)*".

Below are sample table and data that i used  for my practice

```
CREATE TABLE games (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
  city VARCHAR(20),
  name VARCHAR(20)
);     

INSERT INTO games(id,city,name) VALUES (2004,'Athens','football'); 
INSERT INTO games(id,city,name) VALUES (2008,'Beijing','cricket');

SELECT id, COUNT(*) over() as rowcount 
  FROM games g 
 where name='football' 
 GROUP BY CASE 
            WHEN name='football' 
            THEN g.name 
          END;
```

What is the invalid character in the select statement ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the `CASE` within the `GROUP BY`. Also, `GROUP BY` is not required, since you are already filtering the `football` rows in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) OVER() as rowcount 
FROM games g 
WHERE name = 'football'
```

When you use an analytic function, such as `COUNT(*) OVER()`, you don't need to use `GROUP BY`. They serve different purposes.

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f32cf/4)**.

Comment: You're right about the analytic function and group by not being required, and inapplicable for this scenario; but there's nothing wrong with CASE in a GROUP BY - this won't cause the "invalid character" error (although perhaps it won't work in older database versions).

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp I have the case that i Should use GROUP BY Clause with CASE, when i used like above Oracle is throwing the above error. What might be the reson. Any guess ?

Comment: you need to show your work. Show the exact query you're attempting to run, and show the full error message.